# Adding the Calendar API from Google to a Spring Maven Project in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I have been trying to use the Google Calendar API using the Quickstart.java in a Spring Maven project. I have been following the steps given on https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java. I have the code working up until I get an error when I put the "gradle -q run" command.  The error is: 
"Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details."

Not sure how to fix this issue any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'Quickstart'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev285-1.23.0'


}
```

Comment: Show us your gradle file and the compiler error, otherwise we can only guess what the error might be.

Comment: Apologies I have edited the question @GeorgHenkel

Comment: "Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details." Are there any details? Correct JDK installed? Must be JDK 8

Comment: Yes I have the jdk1.8.0_111 installed @GeorgHenkel

Comment: What does the compiler say? You have any compiler errors?

Comment: It says "Execution failed for task ':compileJava'." @GeorgHenkel

Comment: I have also been getting errors like this: "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\eeworkspace\Project\src\main\java\com\fyp\account\service\UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:13: error: package org.springframework.transaction.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;" @GeorgHenkel

Comment: Your problems depends on missing dependencies to your spring framework. You need to add them to the gradle dependencies, too.

Comment: That got rid of the small errors with the missing dependencies. It then game me an error on:                                                                       
"Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\eeworkspace\Project\build.gradle' line: 17

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Project'.
> Supplied String module notation 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'. " @GeorgHenkel

Comment: I am no Gradle expert, sorry. Using Maven all the time.

Comment: No problem I appreciate your help with the other issue

Comment: I think you must add it in this form: `compile 'org.springframework:spring-tx:2.5.4'`